# pseudocode of gradient descent

Tags: java, machine-learning

I'm going to describe the procedure for gradient descent using the language of English:

**1)** For all of the files (e.g. documents) in our training corpus.

--> commence, now we are considering our first document

**2)** For all the features in the feature vector associated with that training example (document)

**3)** Take the dot product of the vector of weight values * and the vector of features specific to the document under consideration

* *vector of weight values is applicable to all features, though all features will not be present in all documents, indeed only some features will be present in each individual document*

**4)** Take the value resulting from step 3 and apply this to our loss function. I'm using the Hinge Loss function, i.e. the formula

[image]

Is that equation saying that the hinge loss objective function should be the sum of the misclassification error for every file in our training set?

So is that equivalent to the java code:

```
Math.max(0, 1 - y * value_from_step_three)
```

With `y = {-1, 1}`

**^ THIS IS MY FIRST POINT OF CONFUSION**

I guess that is inaccurate but I'm not sure, according to my mental model it should be right.

**5)** For every weight, update it as:

new weight value<sub>j</sub> = old weight value<sub>j</sub> - learning rate * *value from step 4* * value of feature<sub>j</sub>.

I'm a bit confused about what *value of feature<sub>j</sub>* should be, since I guess this would correspond to a vector, that has values for every weight under consideration, i.e.

Example:

```
Document 1 = ["I", "am", "awesome"]
Document 2 = ["I", "am", "great", "great"]
```

Dictionary is:

```
["I", "am", "awesome", "great"]
```

So the documents as a vector would look like:

```
Document 1 = [1, 1, 1, 0]
Document 2 = [1, 1, 0, 2]
```

There will be weights:

[Weight<sub>"I"</sub>, Weight<sub>"am"</sub>, Weight<sub>"awesome"</sub>, Weight<sub>"great"</sub>]

There's also a weight for bias isn't it?

Comment: The `y = {-1, 1}` is so it works. It's by definition. I know this isn't very useful, but the loss function was defined in this way.

Comment: would you please clarify that comment? I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Simply put. The loss function measures how "bad" the current solution is. There is ton of loss functions in the wild. But author of this exercise have chosen Hinge Loss function, which happens to be defined in range [-1,1]. You should probably start with basic gradient descent algorithm and then move to this problem.